# 3-pane looping scrolling panel -- suggestions

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a UI implementation challenge (at least for me). The desire is for a scrolling view of 3 panes that loops endlessly: when the user swipes right from pane2 to pane3, they should be able to keep scrolling right to pane1 and on through the panes, repeating endlessly. One and only one full pane is shown at a time--there's no hanging edge.

Something like this:
[image: 3 pane panorama]

All the examples I've found are very elaborate, with databinding and viewmodels, generally based on ListBoxes/views. We don't need anything that sophisticated: our 3 panes aren't dynamic and there are always 3.

Our current implementation, which scrolls only back and forth between pane1 and pane3 (which met the previous requirement), follows the MSDN WinRT controls example:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel>
    <Grid /> <!-- pane1 -->
    <Grid /> <!-- pane2 -->
    <Grid /> <!-- pane3 -->
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works fine so far as it goes, as we have the touch experience, and the content follows the user's finger and is visible while they scroll.

My thinking so far is:

- add another grid on the 'start' and 'end'
- figuring out the horizontal offset while scrolling
- once halfway through a panel, copy/insert the 'last' pane contents into the 'next' pane

But I don't know if this will work, and overall am not sure how to go about it. We are looking for something very simple just to get the point across and for usability testing, but it must really work in C#/XAML (a Windows Store app). So I am asking wiser people for suggestions.

Comment: Are you wanting to only display one at a time, or are the sides of the non displaying panels showing a bit on the left and right?

Comment: Only the current pane is fully shown..there's no leading edge on the side. Touching and seeing the content scroll is necessary, so a FlipView doesn't work. Amended question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :  [Create a custom ItemsPanel for an ItemsControl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx)

It descibes to create two ItemsPanel : The first will generate a circle with all items and the second will generate an infinite looping list.

Comment: Thanks--this looks like someone with more dev skills can start with. We also need to add snap points for the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `ScrollViewer` since it doesn't loop and has scroll bars or indicators that show your view port position in the scrollable content. A `FlipView` would work a bit better, but it doesn't support looping either. The solution I would recommend would be to simply implement it from scratch. Put all panels in a `Canvas` that is the same size as the panels and handle `ManipulationDelta` events from the panels (you need to give them at least a `Transparent` `Background` for successful hit testing and `ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateInertia"`) and call `Canvas.SetLeft(panel)` on the panels to update their positions by `e.Delta.Translation.X` taken from the event argument. If the position goes below `-panel.ActualWidth` add `3 * panel.ActualWidth` and if it goes above - subtract that amount. Make sure to also add buttons to enable flipping items with a mouse if you decide to filter out manipulation events when `e.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse` as manifested in the `FlipView` control, though I would personally prefer to keep mouse-drag manipulations.